# Angular2 rc-3 No provider for Http! (Resource -> Http)

Tags: http, angular, angular2-services

I don't know why, but my plugin [ng2-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-rest) isn't working on RC-3 angular2.

I have service **Resource**:

```
@Injectable()
export class Resource<E, T, TA> {

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http,
        @Inject(Jsonp) private jp: Jsonp) {

    }
...
```

plus I am using inside this service class **Rest**:

```
export class Rest<T, TA> {

    constructor(private endpoint: string,private http: Http, private jp: ) {
        ...
    }
 ...
```

What is going on in DI in Angular2  RC-3 ?
Everything works fine on RC-1, but now I am getting 
very nasty error:

> No provider for Http! (Resource -> Http)

I have tried lots of things: including Resource, HTTP_PROVIDER, HTTP_BINDING in bootstrap, removing inject... but nothing works.

Comment: `@Inject` is redundant in [injectable class](https://github.com/darekf77/ng2-rest/blob/master/src/resource.service.ts#L16-L19), not sure if this may contribute to the problem. Usually you provide `HTTP_PROVIDER` in parent injector and inject `Http` in service, it is straightforward. I guess this may happen if the app and addon refer to *different* `@angular/http` packages (even if semver is the same, there can be dupe packages in nested `node_modules`, they could be eliminated with `npm dedupe`). So it depends on how you build the app.

Comment: I believe that most breaking changes happened in RC2. And RC4 is already there. Btw, nice addon, bookmarked it!

Comment: @estus thanks! It looks like, without npm_modules  in plugin folder everything works.

Comment: For this reason IMO is it a good thing for third-party item to export all providers as a constant, including the ones it depends on (like HTTP...), see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622#issuecomment-193302391). In a scenario like that the app may end up bloated with duplicate http modules (I guess that the developer will spot the mistake when duplicate Http will appear as unmockable in specs) but will still be workable.